# Haskell using foldl like recursion

Tags: haskell, recursion, types, fold

I'm trying to get a function working that uses foldl
to go through a list of tuples and create a string from it.
I'm trying to create a similar function that already works using recursion.

Here is the code that I'm trying to compile:

```
citeBook :: (String, String, Integer) -> String
citeBook (name, titl, date) = (titl ++ " (" ++ name ++ ", " ++ show date ++ ")\n")

--Recursion function
-- function must be called with putStr in order for newlines to work
bibliography_rec :: [(String, String, Integer)] -> String
bibliography_rec [] = ""
bibliography_rec xs = (citeBook(head xs) ++ bibliography_rec (tail xs))

--foldl function 
bibliography_fold :: [(String, String, Integer)] -> String
bibliography_fold [] = ""
bibliography_fold (x:xs) = foldl (++) citeBook(x) xs   --ERROR HERE
```

So in the very last line of the provided code, I am trying to have foldl
use (++) as the operator in order to combine the strings in the list.
I'm using citeBook(x) as my base case, since x will be the first tuple
taken from the list. Note that citeBook(x) returns a string. Then continue
folding with the list xs.

Here are the errors I'm getting. I think my parameter types for foldl aren't 
matching up with what is expected, but everything seems okay to me..

```
hw1.hs:28:34:
    Couldn't match type `[a0]'
                  with `(String, String, Integer) -> String'
    Expected type: ((String, String, Integer) -> String)
                   -> [a0] -> (String, String, Integer) -> String
      Actual type: [a0] -> [a0] -> [a0]
    In the first argument of `foldl', namely `(++)'
    In the expression: foldl (++) citeBook (x) xs
    In an equation for `bibliography_fold':
        bibliography_fold (x : xs) = foldl (++) citeBook (x) xs

hw1.hs:28:48:
    Couldn't match expected type `[[a0]]'
                with actual type `(String, String, Integer)'
    In the third argument of `foldl', namely `(x)'
    In the expression: foldl (++) citeBook (x) xs
    In an equation for `bibliography_fold':
        bibliography_fold (x : xs) = foldl (++) citeBook (x) xs

hw1.hs:28:51:
    Couldn't match expected type `(String, String, Integer)'
                with actual type `[(String, String, Integer)]'
    In the fourth argument of `foldl', namely `xs'
    In the expression: foldl (++) citeBook (x) xs
    In an equation for `bibliography_fold':
        bibliography_fold (x : xs) = foldl (++) citeBook (x) xs
```

I appreciate any and all feedback. Thanks!

Comment: Isn't `bibliography_rec` just `concatMap citeBook`?

Comment: Yes it is, post that as the answer.

Comment: bheklilr, I just tried that out and it does work, but I was explicitly trying to create a recursive function. My problem is I'm trying to print out a list just like bibliography_rec does, but using foldl instead of recursion

Comment: Some minor notes: first of all, bibliography_rec is associating the concatenations to the right so you should use foldr insread of foldl to get an equivalent function (the result is the same because ++ is associative but the efficiency is better for the right associative version). Additionally, it would be better form to use pattern matching on bibliography_head instead of head and tail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You gave `foldl` the `(++)` function which has type `String -> String -> String`.  However the collection you're folding over, `xs`, has type `[(String, String, Integer)]`, not type `[String]`.

You could change `bibliography_fold` to

```
bibliography_fold :: [(String, String, Integer)] -> String
bibliography_fold [] = ""
bibliography_fold (x:xs) = foldl (++) (citeBook x) (map citeBook xs)
```

or just to

```
bibliography_fold :: [(String, String, Integer)] -> String
bibliography_fold xs = foldl (++) "" (map citeBook xs)
```

but I'm a relative noob at Haskell myself so take my coding style with a grain of salt.

Also, you need to write `(citeBook x)` and not `citeBook(x)`, or the compiler will assume that `citeBook` and `(x)` are both arguments to `foldl` (correct me if I'm wrong).  This helps explain why the error message you got is so strange-looking.

Comment: I'd emphasize that the `foldl (++) ""` version is much preferable since it doesn't special-case the empty list.

Comment: Thanks jcarpenter! That worked out very well. I'm a noob at Haskell myself. I guess I'm not very familiar with the map function. Looks like I'll be doing some research.

Comment: You could also write it without the map function, like this: `bibliography_fold xs = foldl (\s t -> s ++ citeBook t) "" xs`.  Now the accumulator function has type `String -> (String, String, Integer) -> String` and you are folding over a `[(String, String, Integer)]` again.

Comment: I would definitely avoid `foldl (++)` because of the nasty quadratic overhead. Use `foldr` instead here.

Answer (score 3):

You've already gotten your answer, so I'll provide another way of using a fold to solve this problem:

```
bibliography_fold :: [(String, String, Integer)] -> String
bibliography_fold = foldr ((++) . citeBook) ""
```

There's no maps, no special cases, and it can be written in point free style.  I'd encourage you to deconstruct this expression in GHCi and inspect each component using `:info` to explore how it actually works.  Look at the types of `foldr`, `++`, `citeBook`, `(++) . citeBook`, see if you can figure out why this works.  You may want to look up the source code for `foldr` as well.

Comment: +1 for suggesting to use foldr here instead of foldl